# SQL Server 2012 analysing data from previous month with epoch time

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, epoch

Newbie here...

I have been set a challenge to report data from the previous calendar month on a SQL Server 2012 database, but time stamps are set by Epoch time. This is a bit of a challenge to refer the query I have written to the previous month.

Any help would be great.

```
DECLARE @fromDate AS DATETIME 
DECLARE @toDate AS DATETIME 

SET @fromDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) 
SET @toDate = DATEADD(DAY, 0, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())));

SELECT 
    DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, cm.CREATE_DATE)/30*30,0) 'HALF_HOUR' , 
    COUNT(DISTINCT cm.ACTIVITY_1D) 'ACTIVITY_COUNT' , 
    SUM(cm. EVENT_DURATION) AS AGENT_EVENT_TIME,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(cm.EVENT_DURATION) <== 1800 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE CEILING (SUM(cm.EVENT_DURATION)*1.0/1800) 
    END AS AVG_CONCURRENCY, 
    u.USER NAME 
FROM 
    [dbo].[EGPL_EVENT_HISTORY_CASe_MGMT] cm
JOIN 
    EGPL USER u ON u.USER ID = cm.USER ID 
WHERE 
    cm. CREATE_DATE BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate 
    AND USER NAME  != ' system ' 
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, cm.CREATE_DATE) / 30 * 30, 0), u.USER_NAME
ORDER BY 
    1, 3
```

Further to the comments... this is meant to be run as a monthly task (batch file scripted Scheduled task). i have performed similar queries with standard date/time but hitting a brick wall with epoch.

Thanks

Comment: Don't give image of code please

Comment: just amending now

Answer (score 3):

So the datetime values are stored as an `int` and represent the number of seconds since `1970-01-01`? You want to turn the arguments/parameters into the types present in the table, not the other way around, especially if that column has an index. This assumes you want a month at a time, but is easy to adjust for any range:

```
DECLARE @month datetime = '20190101'; -- don't use regional formats

DECLARE @start int, @end int;
SELECT @start = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', @month);
SET @end = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @month));

SELECT ... FROM [dbo].[EGPL_EVENT_HISTORY_CASe_MGMT] AS cm
  WHERE cm.CREATE_DATE >= @start 
    AND cm.CREATE_DATE <  @end;
```

If you want this thing to do "this month" or "last month" without having to specify, the logic doesn't really change.

This month:

```
DECLARE @month datetime = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1);
-- everything else the same
```

Last month:

```
DECLARE @month datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, 
  DATEADD(DAY,1-DAY(GETDATE()),CONVERT(date, GETDATE())));
-- everything else the same
```

And why you really don't want to use `BETWEEN`, regional formats, and shorthand for both date/time and `ORDER BY`:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad Habits : mis-handling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Bad Habits : date/time shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [Bad Habits : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: thats fine if i want to run it manually.. however as i am declaring from and to date variables so it can be run without modifying the code month on month.. As basically it is run as a monthly Task on the SQL server to gain stats for the previous calendar month, which i have run successfully for standard date/time formats as a script/batch file but struggling with epoch.

Comment: @AndrewLewis That seems like a different problem (and I was modeling after the code you showed us, not something that involves additional things like monthly tasks). It doesn't matter how you define the start and end date, the important part is converting those to epoch offsets instead of trying to apply date/time logic to ints in your table.

Comment: let me try it out!! and i'll get back to you .. :) thanks